# Solving a simple homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y^{(4)}-2y^{(3)}+5y''(x)=0$

Ansatz: $y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$

We find: $P(\lambda)=\lambda^4-2\lambda^3+5\lambda^2=\lambda^2(\lambda^2-2\lambda+5)=0 \quad \Rightarrow \lambda_{1,2}=0, \lambda_{3,4}=1+-2i$

So we find:

$$y_H(x)=A+Bx+e^x[C\cos(2x)+D\sin(2x)]\tag{1}$$

Now, the solution they gave me is this:

$$y_h(x)=k_1+k_2x+\frac{1}{25}\{k_3(4\cos(2x)+3\sin(2x))+k_4(3\cos(2x)-4\sin(2x)-4\sin(2x))\}e^x\tag{2}$$

Now I have no idea how they obtained that. When I plot them I can see they are the same but anyone has any idea how to obtain (2)?

Comment: Constants we need find from initial conditions: $y(x_0)=y_0$,  $y'(x_0)=y_1$,  $y''(x_0)=y_2$,  $y'''(x_0)=y_3$,

Comment: Not entirely sure who "they" is, but the two solutions are equivalent. If you collect all the things multiplying $e^x\cos(2x),$ you'll see that it amounts to an arbitrary constant. The same goes for everything multiplying $e^x\sin(2x)$. If "they" is a CAS like Mathematica, then the answer is you'd have to dive into its documentation.

Comment: yeah I also though like that and I also confirmed that the solutions are the same - but I am very curious to know how that other solution was derived. (Can't ask them atm). They being the people who made the exersice sheet.

Comment: Are $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$ the initial conditions?

Comment: Yeah - to be determined by some initial values.